How to get a French simcard without a French address?
A lot of my friends who expatriated to France had the same problem : the French catch 22.
To get a French simcard you need a french address, to get a french address you need a french bank account, to get a french bank account you need a french simcard.
Not necessarily in that order. But a lot of people spend weeks figuring it out.

But it's possible to do all of that in 4 hours.
Step 1 is to go to this free mobile shop or any other free mobile shop : https://maps.app.goo.gl/1NbDz1hMgz6eWxra9
There they have a vending machine which distributes simcards.
These are real simcards, not prepaid, and free mobile is not a bad option if you plan to live in France.
Go to the vending machine or talk to the shop guy and all you need is a Visa or Mastercard to pay 29€ for your simcard.
It will ask for an address or an email but in fact this address is not used for anything at all, so you can just type anything, they won't check and they won't care.
Step 2 Once you have your simcard, download Revolut or N26 or any local online bank.
They need a French phone number, well good news you have one now.
Then Revolut will only ask for a picture of your visa, it doesn't matter if you have a residence permit (carte de sejour) or not, only a valid visa is enough. (last I checked it was)
Once your revolut online account is opened, you are few clicks away in the Revolut app to convert it to an actual bank account, and they won't ask for any additional infos.
Tadaaa, it's done, in less than 4 hours after you landed you have a French phone number and an actual French bank account with a domestic RIB.
